# Android Studio AVD not working HAXM not installing

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, android-virtual-device, haxm

When I'm running AVD and select a device to run, if I use armeabi-v7a then the loading screen appears and after it loads it just disappears and no virtual device shows up.

When I change it to x86 then I get this error

> " Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: emulator: ERROR: x86
>   emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! Please ensure
>   Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable. CPU acceleration status:
>   HAX kernel module is not installed! "

So I installed it using SDK manager but I got this error

> "Failed to configure driver: unknown error. Failed to open driver"

so I used this workaround patch

https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/04/25/workaround-patch-for-haxm-installation-error-failed-to-configure-driver-unknown

but when I run "hax_extract" windows command script it just opens up and closes(I even turned off Firewall and Right now I dont have any antivirus installed either) and still I get the same errors when opening the emulator.

I'm using Windows 10 and according to "Intel(R) Processor Identification Utility" Virtualization is enabled.

Using Asus Z97 Maximus VII HERO mobo
Intel I7 4790k

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure that you have **enabled** the VT in Bios. Notice that "Intel(R) Processor Identification Utility" just tells you that the Virtualization is supported, not enabled certainly.

Secondly, make sure that you have **disabled** the Hyper-V if you have used Hyper-V in your Windows. You can go to http://www.poweronplatforms.com/enable-hyper-v to disable it.

Under normal circumstances, the problem should be solved. However, if you still get same error, you can try this: **disable secure boot** in BIOS, and then install haxm. This is my final solution when I once encountered such problem.

Good luck!